# SQL создает не те значение которые передают

Tags: python, mysql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

Есть БД на сервере(MySQL,phpmyadmin)

Добавляю данные через python(PyMySQL) но за место передаваемых значений в поле добавляются другие

```
def add_user(user_id,referal_id = None):
    date = datetime.datetime.today().date()
    logging.info(date)
    with conection.cursor() as cursor:
        if referal_id != None:
            with conection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO user (user_id,data_reg,referal_id) VALUES ({user_id},{date},{referal_id})")
                conection.commit()
        else:
            with conection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO user (user_id,data_reg) VALUES ({user_id},{date})")
                conection.commit()
```

date = datetime.datetime.today().date() = 2023-09-22

Но в data_reg добавляется 1992 а должно 2023-09-22
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что здесь может быть не так, всю голову уже сломал

Comment: Всё правильно, 2023 - 9 - 22 = 1992 как и должно быть. Вы хоть проверяйте, какие sql-запросы у вас получаются

Comment: `cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO user (user_id,data_reg,referal_id) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (user_id, date, referal_id,))`